# diagonalizing a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, diagonalization

I have this problem: Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2i & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$ Find a $N\in\mathbb GL(3,\mathbb C) $ such that $N^{t}A\overline N$ is diagonal

The matrix A is $2\ x\ 2$ so I have tried with a certain  $N = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ . My professor tried with this matrix and said $N^{t}A\overline N$=  $NA\overline N{^t}$ why?

After he has obtained the following system of equation: $2ia\overline a+b\overline a+a\overline b=0$ and   $2ic\overline c+d\overline c+c\overline d=0$ but how do I find this coefficient $a,b,c,d$ ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: $GL(3,\Bbb C)$? And $N^*$ is ordinarily called the hermitian adjoint, not conjugate (it's the conjugate of the transpose).

Comment: Such that what about $N^{-1}AN^*?$ Such that it is diagonal?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews my professor wrote the text of exercise in a wrong way now i have corrected it. Can you still help me?

Comment: @TedShifrin my professor wrote the text of exercise in a wrong way now i have corrected it. Can you still help me?

Comment: Shouldn't $N$ be a member of $GL(\color{red}{2},\mathbb C)$ when $A$ is $2\times2$?

Comment: Also, your two equations are not solvable. The equation $2ia\overline a+b\overline a+a\overline b=0$ implies that $2i|a|^2=-2\operatorname{Re}(a\overline b)$. Since the LHS is purely imaginary and the RHS is real, both sides must be zero. Hence $a=0$. Similarly $c=0$ in the other equation. But then $N$ is singular.

Comment: @user1551 thanks for your answer i also think is $\ GL(2,\mathbb C)$ , i think my professor  made a mistake. But now i have another question   why  $N{^t}A\overline N$ is equal to $NA\overline N^ {t}$ ? My professor used this to solve the problem but i don't know where does it come from. Thanks again

Comment: They are not equal.